# What is this brown spider with black and white stripes? (Atlanta, Georgia)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

**Location**: [Atlanta, Georgia](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjK0s7traPUAhUT1GMKHTIwB1QQFgguMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAtlanta&usg=AFQjCNGFYXfiiCEhI0x4D9yGmzv4Aun9AA&sig2=7Atr6I0gqksZDRAN9W3-vA)

Spider mostly brown, with black and white stripes. Would fit on a teaspoon.  Ran quickly but not very far when I tried to catch it.

<sub>Click to *zoom in* the pictures below:</sub>

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It resembles ***[Dolomedes tenebrosus](http://www.spiders.us/species/dolomedes-tenebrosus/)***, commonly called the **Dark Fishing Spider**, and it belongs to the family **[Pisauridae](https://ednieuw.home.xs4all.nl/australian/Pisauridae/Pisauridae.html)**.

[image: Spider]

**Image Source**: **[Bug Guide](http://bugguide.net/node/view/52988)**

Males are **generally thinner in profile than the females**, which is well depicted below.

[image: Spider male-female comparison]

**Image Source**: **[Spiders.Us](http://www.spiders.us/species/filter/brown/)**

Based on the pictures provided, you seem to have captured a male ***Dolomedes tenebrosus***.

Comment: Based on the OP's description of size, I'd say they found a male (7-13mm)

Comment: @theforestecologist I would agree. I have updated the answer to include that information.